# How to get the friends activities using twitter api?

Tags: c#, wpf, twitter

I am not able to get list or collection from twitter api which returns my friends activities.

Basically I want the list of activities of my friends just like the twitter has activity or interaction section on its website.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: hi @DiogoMoreira -- I'm using wpf C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a Site stream. First, get a list of your friends ID's, then add them to the site stream. Here's an example using LINQ to Twitter:

```
        Console.WriteLine("\nStreamed Content: \n");
        int count = 0;

        (from strm in twitterCtx.UserStream
         where strm.Type == UserStreamType.Site &&
               strm.Follow == "15411837,16761255"
         select strm)
        .StreamingCallback(strm =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strm.Content + "\n");

            if (count++ >= 10)
            {
                strm.CloseStream();
            }
        })
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

You can find more info in the [LINQ to Twitter Documentation](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stream%20Multiple%20User%20Messages&referringTitle=Streaming%20Twitter%20Content).

Also, regardless of what technology you go with, you should read [Twitter's Site Streams documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/site).

NOTE: Twitter site streams is in Beta, so you'll need to contact them for access.

Comment: thanks @Joe Mayo -- Sorry for not mentioning the library name, I'm using TweetSharp library, will you provide the same example using TweetSharp.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to monitor your friends on Twitter you need to use the UserStream (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/user).

Whilst its implementation is missing some features of the UserStream the Tweetinvi API gives the ability to easily detect what your friends do on twitter.

Here is an example :

```
// Register the Twitter Credentials
IToken token = new Token("userKey", "userSecret", "consumerKey", "consumerSecret");

// Create the stream
IUserStream userStream = new UserStream();

// Register to an event that triggers when a tweet is created by a user you follow
userStream .TweetCreatedByAnyoneButMe += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tweet '{0}' created by {1}!", args.Value.Text, args.Value.Creator.Id);
};
// Start the stream
userStream.StartStream(token);
```

This code is going to call the Console.Writeline() each time a Tweet is created by a user you follow!

As I said all the features are not implemented yet but you can already listen to many **different events like Tweets, Messages, Follows...** as well as filtering the Tweets you receive (which is not possible by default with Twitter UserStream).

Hope this will help you :)

EDIT : You can find the API there -> http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/